# Save embedded document request via mongoose

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, mongoose

I am using MEAN stack in my development. I face a problem when to save embedded document. For saving a flat document, following code is apply. But i do not know how to save the embedded document.

```js
var ChildSchema = new Schema({
 columnA: {
  type: String
 },
 columnB: {
  type: String
 }
});


var ParentSchema = new Schema({
 colummC: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  required: 'Please fill Product name',
  trim: true
 },
 columnD: {
  type: Number,
  default: 0,
  required: 'Please fill Product price',
  trim: true
 },
 child: [ChildSchema]  
});


exports.create = function(req, res) {
    var parent = new Parent(req.body);

    parent.save(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(parent);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<form ng-submit = create()>
 <input type="text" ng-model="columnC">
 <input type="text" ng-model="columnD">
</form>
```

I am expecting something like this(tweaking done in angular only), but not sure if this exist.

```
<form ng-submit = create()>
    <input type="text" ng-model="columnC">
    <input type="text" ng-model="columnD">

    <input type="text" ng-model="child[0].columnA">
    <input type="text" ng-model="child[0].columnB">

    <input type="text" ng-model="child[1].columnA">
    <input type="text" ng-model="child[1].columnB">
</form>
```

Comment: what is the problem..

Comment: Able to save successfully but @NaeemShaikh the child(embedded data) is not inserted.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh i forgot to pass it to controller. How should this array list be passed into the controller?

Comment: nvm i have found the solution